# Como determinar o tipo de dado mais adequado para um campo numérico de tamanho fixo?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

Estou com uma dúvida quanto a característica de alguns atributos de minha tabela.

Problema: tenho que guardar um número de identificação de meus itens, este é composto sempre por 3 dígitos (zero a esquerda em caso de números inferiores a 3 dígitos). Posso gravar o número final de forma literal no banco, assim como posso gravar ignorando o 0 (zero) a esquerda e tratar isso na aplicação. Acredito que para gravar com zero a esquerda terei que usar o tipo de dado `char(3)`, já para gravar o número inteiro devo usar `smallint(3)`.

Obs: considerar ainda que os tipos de dados citados consome:

- smallint = 2 bytes
- char = 1 byte

Considerando que este é um número de identificação que não possui relacionamento e não será utilizado para formulas de calculo, existe alguma regra que determine o tipo de dado mais adequado para essa coluna, considerando ainda **performance** (no meu contexto performance é prioridade) e *storage*?

Obs: Meu ambiente é composto por um `Laravel 5.6, php 7.2 e MySQL 5.7`

Comment: se quer gravar na sua base `001`, `022`, `333` ?

Comment: Se você quer preencher con zeros a esquerda em um campo inteiro use [zerofill](http://rogeralmeida.com.br/blog/2011/03/25/mysql-para-que-servem-unsigned-e-zerofill/), não tem como usar auto_increment em colunas do tipo texto

Comment: @VirgilioNovic isso, porém, o problema não esta em gerar a sequência numérica. Mas determinar o melhor tipo de dado no banco. Estou em dúvida entre considerar o tipo char e já enviar a string "002", ou considerar o tipo smallint, enviar o número inteiro e na aplicação fazer o tratamento para inserir os zeros a esquerda. Dúvida quanto a abordagem em si, como fazer é simples, não posso usar zerofill pois o banco pode mudar, estou tentando trabalhar só com o que é permitido dentro das migrations do Laravel para estrutura as tabelas.

Comment: Eu salvaria como inteiro e depois trataria da sua formatação na aplicação. no Laravel isso seria tratado pelos `mutators` no Laravel

Comment: Sinceridade, a sua pergunta pode ser considerada como baseados em opiniões, porque, se pode fazer das duas formas,não compromete em nada desempenho, mesmo tendo diferença em bytes. Eu faria como te disse, mas, se colocar char com 3 posições também está correto

Comment: Se o objetivo é performance, pq não salvar como inteiro e tratar o retorno?

Answer (score 1):

Em termos de performance tanto faz, mudará nanossegundos em algo que deve demorar milissegundos.

Vai obter mais performance tunando o banco de dados do que fazer isso.

A conta do espaço ocupado nem sempre é tão simples, e vai mudar muito pouco para você.

Se quer que seja incrementado automaticamente só dá para ser numérico.

Se o código é um texto, o certo é um char(3) e teria que adminsitrar o incremento.

Tem quem dê uma solução usando ambos, um para incrementar e ser chave primária e outro para mostrar o código como deve ser.